# Trying to do CONCAT with COUNT in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to concatenate a string with an aggregate function in one simple line in SQL. I tried the middle column without select and several other things (including cast conversion to varchar within that parameter), but to no avail. I've also tried searching on the internet and can't find what I need. If you can help, it'd be much appreciated.

`select CONCAT('blank had ', select COUNT(*) from table_name where message like '%fail%', ' today.')`

Comment: Try to enclose your  select count(*) query in parenthesis()

Comment: You should add a tag with your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries need their own parentheses, so you can write this as:

```
select CONCAT('blank had ',
              (select COUNT(*) from table_name where message like '%fail%'),
              ' today.'
             )
```

Comment: Isn't there a `)` missing somewhere?